# Change fontsize of Chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, fontsize

Hi I can not seem to figure out how to increase the size of font in my chapter heading. My code look like this

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filleft}
{{\chapnamefont\chaptertitlename}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
   \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
   \hspace{.8em}%
   \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
  }%
}%
{15pt}
{\chaptitlefont} 

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{40pt}
```

And the current layout looks like this
[image]

Comment: A complete MWE please, i.e. complete working code that demonstrates the problem that you have.

Comment: Which element of your chapter header should be larger?

Comment: Where do all those skips come from?

Comment: @samcarter The text reading DUMMY CHAPTER

Comment: @Bernand The style is copy-pasted from someone else thus I unfortunately can not explain the code

Comment: @J.Doe My guess would be that you have to change something in the definition of `\chaptitlefont`, but without having a MWE which shows how this is defined...

Comment: @J.Doe, please post your MWE, like JPi said, it is impossible to solve otherwise.